# Do the metrics $d$ and $\frac{d}{1+d}$ induce the same uniformity?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, examples-counterexamples, uniform-continuity, uniform-spaces

Let $d_1$ and $d_2$ be two metrics on the same set $M$.  Then $d_1$ and $d_2$ are called uniformly equivalent if the identity maps $i:(M,d_1)\rightarrow(M,d_2)$ and $i^{-1}:(M,d_2)\rightarrow(M,d_1)$ are uniformly continuous.  Now [this textbook](https://books.google.com/books?id=4VFDVy1NFiAC&lpg=PA121&ots=la7WemUl_k&dq=%22strongly%20equivalent%22%20%22uniformly%20equivalent%22&pg=PA121#v=onepage&q&f=false) gives the following exercise:

> Given any metric space $(M,d)$, show that the metric $\rho=\frac{d}{1+d}$ is always uniformly equivalent to $d$[.]

My question is, is the result of the exercise correct?  Because two metrics are uniformly equivalent if and only if they induce the same uniformity, and if two metrics induce the same uniformity then they have the same bounded sets.  Yet all sets are bounded with respect to $\frac{d}{1+d}$, whereas all sets need not be bounded with respect to $d$.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Presumably you need $i^{-1}$ to be uniformly continuous as well?

Comment: They need not have same bounded sets. They admit same totally bounded sets. Lepschitz equivalence metrics admit the same bounded subsets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The textbook you linked distinguishes between $3$ types of equivalence:

•strong equivalence

•uniform equivalence &

•equivalence.

Evidently the condition that the identity map and its inverse be uniformly continuous corresponds to *uniform equivalence*.  But strong equivalence is stronger, and is the one for which bounded sets are preserved.

As pointed out in the text, $\rho\le C\sigma$ may fail under uniform equivalence.  In particular,  it may fail when $\sigma =\frac{\rho}{1+\rho}$.

Comment: But don't uniformly equivalent metrics induce the same uniformity?  And don't metrics which induce the same uniformity have the same bounded sets?

Comment: Apparently not.

Comment: So which part is wrong?  Is it not true that two metrics are uniformly equivalent if and only if they induce the same uniformity?  Or is it not true that metrics that induce the same uniformity have the same bounded sets?

Comment: I didn't see the "uniformity" terminology anywhere,  though admittedly I only looked at a small portion.

Comment: Uniformities aren't discussed in that book at all.  But see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_space

Comment: I took a quick look.   My guess is that what you're calling "uniformity" corresponds to "strong equivalence".  Not to "uniform equivalence".  We do have uniform equivalence here.  But, as you noted,  the same sets are not necessarily bounded.

Comment: I'm actually leaning towards the other possibility, namely that metrics which are uniformly equivalent do induce the same uniformity, but that perhaps metrics that induce the same uniformity need not have the same bounded sets.  Hopefully someone else can come and clear this all up.

Comment: OK, looks like my guess was correct; see pages 5-6 here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.3249.pdf So I’ll accept your answer.

Comment: Makes sense.   They induce the same topology,  but not the same bounded sets.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the exercise is correct, and $\mathcal{U}(d) = \mathcal{U}(d')$ where $d'=\frac{d}{1+d}$. In the latter uniformity all subsets of $X$ are $d'$-bounded but the $\mathcal{U}(d')$-bounded sets are not always the same as the $d'$-bounded sets. $d$ and $d'$ induce the same uniform structure (and thus the same uniform-bounded and totally-bounded bornologies) but not the same metric bornologies.